# MSBuildWorkspace.Create() - Supported languages is zero

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am using the roslyn `Formatter.Format()` method to format some c#.

One of the parameters takes a `Workspace` object which can be created using `MSBuildWorkspace.Create()`.

However, when I run the code I get a runtime exception because the workspace comes back with no supported languages. If I run this in console application it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to deploy Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.dll and/or Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces.dll with your app.

The workspace dynamically discovers which languages it has support for by loading those assemblies.